# How to cumulate (scan) Deedle data frame values

Tags: f#, deedle

I'm loading a sequence of records into a deedle data frame (from a database table). Is it possible to accumulate (for example sum cumulatively) the values, and get back a data frame? For example there is Series.scanValues but there is no Frame.scanValues. There is Frame.map, but it didn't do what I expected, it left all values as they were.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"Fsharp.Charting"
#load @"..\..\Deedle.fsx"
#endif

open FSharp.Charting
open FSharp.Charting.ChartTypes
open Deedle

type SeriesX = {
    DataDate:DateTime
    Series1:float
    Series2:float
    Series3:float
}

let rnd = new System.Random()
rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5

let data = 
    [for i in [100..-1..1] -> 
                        {SeriesX.DataDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(float -i)
                         SeriesX.Series1 = rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5
                         SeriesX.Series2 = rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5
                         SeriesX.Series3 = rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5
                        }
    ]

# now comes the deedle frame:
let df = data |> Frame.ofRecords
let df = df.IndexRows<DateTime>("DataDate")
df.["Series1"] |> Chart.Line
df.["Series1"].ScanValues((fun acc x -> acc + x),0.0) |> Chart.Line

let df' = df |> Frame.mapValues (Seq.scan (fun acc x -> acc + x) 0.0) 
df'.["Series1"] |> Chart.Line
```

The last two lines just give me back the original values while I would like to have the accumulated values like in df.["Series1"].Scanvalues for Series1, Series2, and Series3.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what you want to get.

Comment: If you run the following code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kiPOy4 you will get the following result: http://pastebin.com/30MBT9Y2 . As you can see - can easily add columns in the frame.

Comment: You also can use style F# : `df.["Series1"] |> Series.scanValues((+)) 0.0`

Comment: @FoggyFinder Thanks for looking into this. Yes, it's a bit convoluted, so let me clarify: I would like to cumulate all three series. In pseudocode df |> Frame.scanValue((+)) 0.0 This would accumulate each series in the Frame. For your code it will go from 1 to 55 for Series 1 and Series 2 and Series 3.

Comment: Hmm, then you can do so: http://pastebin.com/LEG8vT1d

Comment: If this is not what you need, it will be easier to continue in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f Ping me, when will you have time

Comment: @FoggyFinder thanks very much. Probably this should do: Series.mapValues(Series.scanValues(fun acc v -> acc + (v :?> float)) 0.0). Will test and let you know.

Comment: Great. Then, if that is what you are looking for - need to write the answer. (Question without an answer does not look good =)). Otherwise, we will look for a solution on.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Yes, please could you add this as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you! I tried something similar but didn't cast to float.                     

    let allSum =
        df.Columns
            |> Series.mapValues(Series.scanValues(fun acc v -> acc + (v :?> float)) 0.0)
            |> Frame.ofColumns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105658/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-s952163).

Answer (score 1):

> For filtering and projection, series provides Where and Select methods
>   and corresponding Series.map and Series.filter functions (there is
>   also Series.mapValues and Series.mapKeys if you only want to transform
>   one aspect).

So you just apply your function to each Series:

```
let allSum = 
    df.Columns
    |> Series.mapValues(Series.scanValues(fun acc v -> acc + (v :?> float)) 0.0)
    |> Frame.ofColumns
```

and use Frame.ofColumns that to convert the result to the Frame.

**Edit:**

If you need to select only numerics columns, you can use the Frame.getNumericCols:

```
let allSum = 
    df
    |> Frame.getNumericCols
    |> Series.mapValues(Series.scanValues (+) 0.0)
    |> Frame.ofColumns
```

without an explicit type cast code has become more beautiful :)

Comment: Already put into production. Very nice. thank you! Will need to explore Deedle a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Series.scanValues` function. You can obtain a series from every column in your data frame like this: `frame$column`, which gets you a `Series`.

If you need all the columns at once to do the scan, you could first map each row into a single value (a tuple, for example) and the apply the Series.scanValues to that new column.

Comment: I am actually using `Series.scanValues` :)